# UI frameworks for Windows Embedded Compact 7

Tags: windows, user-interface, embedded

We are looking to migrate our automotive diagnostic application from the PC to a Windows Embedded platform. We have an enormous application logic code base which we will migrate to the .net Compact Framework but we are struggling to decide on the UI framework. At the moment we have three options:

1) Silverlight
2) QT
3) Crank

I have a little experience in WPF so I'm naturally drawn to Silverlight but I have zero experience of the others. Have any of you used them on this platform? Can you give me some pros/cons and maybe some potential gotchas?

Cheers,

Chris.

Comment: It's worth noting that a GPU is on-board for graphics acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not tied to .NET and want to have a deployment choice between Windows, Windows Embedded, WinCE, Linux x86/x64 or ARM Embedded Linux you can take a look at:

1. **[fpGUI](http://www.turbocontrol.com/easyfpgui.htm)**
2. **[CodeTyphon](http://www.pilotlogic.com/codetyphon/help/codetyphon_current_status.htm)**

CodeTyphon even includes complete cross platform **[SCADA](http://pascalscada.blogspot.com)** package for visualization and communication with many protocols (MODBUS, Siemens, Allen Bradley and other PLCs).